# PHP verify signed string using public certificate

Tags: php, x509

Based on the very helpful comments below, I've re-written this question.

using the code at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php as an example:

```
<?php
// $data is assumed to contain the data to be signed

// fetch certificate from file and ready it
$fp = fopen("path/file.pem", "r");
$cert = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);

// state whether signature is okay or not
// use the certificate, not the public key
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $cert);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "good";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature";
}
?>
```

We're working on a project where we receive data which contains a "signature". This is known parts of the data (UTF8) which have been signed by the sender using the private x.509 certificate and base64 encoded. As part of the data we receive their public certificate in Base64.

We can contruct the "check data" (`$data`) from information we are sent, and we're sent the `$signature`, so using the above code example *should* work, however...

The example above takes the certificate from the PEM file, but we're just given the Base64 encoded public certificate.

Not having used this sort of thing before, how do I process the Base64 certificate so I can use it as $cert in the above code?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Sammitch for clarification on the Certificate. I can now access the public key from the certificate. However, the `openssl_verify` is still failing to verify, and I'm wondering if this is because of how the raw unsigned data is put together.

`openssl_verify` requires the `$data` to be a string, but in this instance, the data is created as follows:

The signature prefix is a concatenation of the verb, the destination and the date timestamp, so something like:

`POST;https://example.com/webhook;2023-10-12T20:53:50+00:00`

This is then converted to bytes.

The VB.Net process for doing this is this:

```
Dim signaturePrefix As String = verb + ";" + Destination + ";" + SignatureDate + ";"
Dim signaturePrefixBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signaturePrefix)

Dim originalLength As Integer = signaturePrefixBytes.Length

Array.Resize(signaturePrefixBytes, originalLength + hashBytes.Length)

Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, signaturePrefixBytes, originalLength, hashBytes.Length)
```

The hash value of the JSON being sent is also converted to bytes with the two byte arrays then merged. This merged value is then signed using the senders X509 certificate.

**So... given that `openssl_verify` requires `$data` to be a string, but this is a byte array, how do I use `openssl_verify` to verify the signature please?**

Comment: Without knowing the signature detail, I can only suggest you to try `openssl_verify`.

Comment: I suggest you are not giving us enough information for anyone to be able to help you. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly question edited so hopefully you understand what I'm asking... ;-)

Comment: As detailed as [this document](https://miniprogram.gcash.com/docs/miniprogram_gcash/mpdev/call_api). What does "the string is signed by the sender" mean? Is the meaning different from the word "signature"? If not, the line at the beginning of the [openssl_verify manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php) says **openssl_verify — Verify signature**

Comment: Thanks @shingo all the articles I'd seen were using verify to check the certificate... Will try what it provides as an example.

Comment: So the un-encoded form of a certificate is referred to as DER, and what your provider appears to have given you is a base64-encoded DER certificate. A PEM formatted certificate is just a base64'd DER between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` lines. So just slap those on either end and use the code you've already worked out here.

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch. That's solved one problem :-) I've edited the question to detail the next problem

Comment: "This is then converted to bytes" - how? There are many different ways this could be encoded. Also the data is variable length so would require framing.

Comment: @symcbean detail added to question

Comment: There's no metadata there. That's rather worrying. Either you're missing some of the code from the remote system or the code is really badly designed. Unless the URL is a contant, the prefix can't be parsed determinisitcally. The only option is to assume a fixed length for the encoded signature (i.e. locked to a single algorithm) and work backwards.

Comment: The verb is constant: POST, the URL is known (it's where I'm receiving the webhook), and the content hash is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've got to the bottom of this, and this solution works:

```
<?php

// Obtain the necessary headers and context variables
$sentSignatureBase64 = "rYYN6S87D3###REDACTED###MfVYeWA==";
$publicCertBase64 = "MIIHA###REDACTED###O0m/kRrA=";
$signedTimestamp = "2023-10-16T12:00:30+01:00";
$contentHashBase64 = "PT8Zbb###REDACTED###PeZEZ3Tc=";

$verb = "POST";
$destination = "https://webhook.site/###REDACTED###";
$body = "[{\"payload\":{###REDACTED###}}]";

try {
    // Create Certificate
    $public_key_pem="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n". wordwrap($publicCertBase64, 64, "\n", false) ."\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
    $publicCertificate = openssl_pkey_get_public($public_key_pem);

    echo "public_key_pem---------".PHP_EOL;
    echo $public_key_pem.PHP_EOL;
    echo "---------".PHP_EOL;


    echo "Key Details---------".PHP_EOL;
    $keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($publicCertificate);
    var_dump($keyData);
    echo "---------".PHP_EOL;

    // Get bytes for the sent signature
    $sentSignatureBytes = base64_decode($sentSignatureBase64);

    // Build the signature prefix based on the received data
    $receivedSignaturePreifx = $verb . ";" . $destination . ";" . $signedTimestamp . ";";
echo "\$receivedSignaturePreifx = ".$receivedSignaturePreifx.PHP_EOL;
    // Get the SHA-256 hash of the body
    $body = empty($body) ? "{}" : $body;
    $hashBytes = hash('sha256', $body, true);

    // Combine the two sets of bytes
    $combinedBytes = $receivedSignaturePreifx . $hashBytes;

    // Verify the signature
    $isSignatureValid = openssl_verify($combinedBytes, $sentSignatureBytes, $publicCertificate, "sha256WithRSAEncryption") === 1;

    if (!$isSignatureValid) {
        $problemDetail = array(
            "statusCode" => 401,
            "detail" => "Signature failed validation.",
            "isSignatureValid" => $isSignatureValid
        );
        echo json_encode($problemDetail);
        return;
    }

    $results = array(
        "detail" => "Successful verification.",
        "isSignatureValid" => $isSignatureValid
    );
    echo json_encode($results);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $problemDetail = array(
        "statusCode" => 500,
        "detail" => "Error while decrypting signature: " . $ex->getMessage()
    );
    echo json_encode($problemDetail);
    return;
}
?>
```